# android - What is the 1:n relationship between view and viewModel

Tags: android, mvvm

I know view and viewmodel are 1:n.
However, in most examples there was one viewmodel per activity.
ex) mainActivity - mainViewModel , userListActivity - userListViewModel

Shouldn't it be like below if it's a 1:n relationship??
ex) mainActivity - viewModel , userListActivity - viewModel

What does 1:n mean?
Does it mean n activities in one viewmodel?
Does it mean n xml files in one viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the common use-case is *1:1*. But theoretically you could have multiple **ViewModels** serving a view, so that's why the *1:n* relation.

In practice this could be useful if you'd like to share a **ViewModel** between two views for example, or when you have a shared **Flow ViewModel**

So basically in that flow every **View** could communicate with two **ViewModels**: the shared one and one specific for that view:

- Imagine a `SignUp` flow, with two screens user credentials (email, password, etc...) and another one with some preferences (like membership, notification, address or other app specific settings)
- In this case the `SharedFlowViewModel` could hold all the user information, and at the last screen the **Submit** will send the request. All other screens with the individual `ViewModel`s would just handle the individual screen logic: form validation, input enabling/desabling, etc...